# Async POST requests on REST API by multi users and wait for them to complete all in Jmeter

Tags: rest, asynchronous, jmeter

I'm submitting multiple POST submits on a REST API using same input Json. That means multi users (ex: 10000) are submitting the same POST with same Json to measure the performance of POST request, but I need to capture the result of completion on each submission using a GET method and still measure the performance of GET as well. This is a asynchronous process as follows.

- POST submit
- generates an ID1
- wait for processing
- in next step another ID2 will be generated
- wait for processing
- in next step another ID3 will be generated
- wait for processing
- final step is completion.

So I need to create a jmeter test plan that can process this Asynchronous POST submits by multi users and wait for them to be processed and finally capture the completion on each submission. I need to generate a graph and table format report that can show me latency and throughput. Sorry for my lengthy question. Thanks, Santana.

Comment: so when you submit the POST (first step), does it return with ID1, or  instead you need to send GET request to get ID1? Can you clarify? Would be helpful if you extended your scenario to say on each step what you post and what you expect to get back. i.e. "1. send: POST request; receive: ???;" etc

Comment: Sure, thanks. 1. POST submit itself generates (submission id)  ID1 > 2. In the process another ID2 (execution id) will be generated but using GET call I can get execution id ID2 by passing ID1 as regular expression variable but I need to wait to get this ID2 > 3. finally the job ends with completion status and ID3 after sometime. I need to run GET call to get completion status along with ID3 by passing ID1 & ID2. This is actually functional flow and I need to run this with multi users and measure latency and throughput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your clarification in the comment, looks to me like you have a fairly straight forward script, which could be expressed like this:

```
Thread Group
    HTTP Sampler 1 (POST)
        Post-processor: save ID1 as a variable ${ID1}

    Timer: wait for next step to be available

    HTTP Sampler 2 (GET, uses ${ID1})
        Post-processor: save ID2 as a variable ${ID2}

    Timer: wait for next step to be available

    HTTP Sampler 3 (GET, uses ${ID1} and ${ID2})
        Post-Processor: extract completion status
        (Optional) Assertion: check completion status
```

I cannot speak about which Timer specifically to use, or which Post-processor, they depend on specific requests you have.

You don't need to worry about multiple users from JMeter perspective (the variables are always independent for the users), but of course you need to make sure that multiple initial POSTs do not conflict with each other from application perspective (i.e. each post should process independent data)

**Latency** is a part of the [standard interface used to save results in the file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Sample_Result_Save_Configuration). But as JMeter's own doc states, latency measurement is a bit limited in JMeter:

> JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as Wireshark) measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is experienced by a browser or other application client.

**Throughput** is available in some [UI listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report), but can also be calculated in the same way as JMeter calculates it:

> Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time)

using raw data in the file.

If you are planning to run 100-200 users (or for debug purposes), use UI listeners; with the higher load, use non-UI mode of JMeter, and save results in CSV which you can later [analyze](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/LogAnalysis). I say get your test to pass in UI mode first with 100 users, and then setup a more robust multi-machine 10K user test.

Comment: I did this earlier and one step worked fine with regular expression extractor and test controller timer, but the challenge here is one step could take 2 mins. other one could take a minute. Due to this difference i'm wondering if there is a way to poll until step is completed. Also while the steps are being executed, I need record queue status at periodic intervals for every 30secs. Thank you very much for the detailed recommendation.

Comment: I get "status":"submitted", "date":"2016-06-20-09:17:48.739" "status":"completed","date":"2016-06-20-09:22:15.129". Is there any way to capture these values and calculate the elapsed time for each and every run by multi concurrent users. If I can capture IDs from the previous request and map the calculated elapsed time in one table, that will be a great report. I don't know if there is a way to achieve this in Jmeter. thanks.